# Are there any way to know whether user open the UAC dialog

Tags: video, windows-vista, uac

I have a simple video player SW, but the render window goes black or freezes after UAC message on Vista 32 or 64. Are there any way to know whether user open the UAC dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/198-c-code-to-detect-uac-elevation-on-vista.html) might be of interest to you, if you meant programatically

Other ways would to read the registry key at

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System Value EnableLUA